# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161.

Tags: laravel-5.1

Am trying to create a login form using 'http://localhost/myproject/public/auth/login' but i keep getting that error.
    Below is my `routes.php` :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

I have also create `resources\views\auth\login.blade.php` file. Can anyone please help since i'm following Laravel 5.1 on this but can't quite know whats wrong.

Comment: I'm curious, can you see any page? What about the welcome page? If yes, what is the URL you are using?

Comment: @Gaz_Edge The welcome page is OK. It's displaying the Laravel statement. I can't quite figure out the reason.

Comment: what is the url of the welcome page? Provide that as I think I know the problem

Comment: In fact i have done a migration and it works now. Funny but the truth. @Gaz_Edge, Thanks for your concern mate

Comment: Hmmm find that hard to believe, but glad it's fixed anyway.

Comment: Hehe..in fact I also am surprised.  thanks